# Kibana + APM: Only one trace sample is shown

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have Elastic + Kibana + APM in Kubernetes with the official helm charts.

Everything seems to be working correctly, except that I can't see all trace data. In the trace sample section only one is shown, always:

[image]

1. There are definitely at least 2 requests in the current filter (shown in the other graphs)
2. Sample rate is definitely 1.0
3. elastic + kibana + APM version is 7.13.0 (also tried in 7.10.1 - exactly the same issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crazy, but the solution was so simple. In order to see the other traces, I needed to click on the "Latency distribution" buckets:

[image]

It's a funny story to tell my team mates, including how many hours I've spent figuring this out, and how I eventually figured it out (I had to reverse engineer the javascript logic...)

Cheers for kibana UX experts.